# Is there any cross-platform GUI library for C++ (with platform dependent UI and scripting based layout)?

Tags: c++, user-interface, cross-platform

Generally I seak for [ASL](http://stlab.adobe.com/) analogs for not only Windows and Mac OS X but once that would work on Linux. Qt GUI is not an option for me. Some simple scripting language that does not require precompilation for GUI to work (like in [ASL Adam and Eve](http://stlab.adobe.com/group__asl__overview.html#asl_overview_adam_and_eve_architecture) even XML would do=)

What I need from such a library - possibility to position some subset of OS default UI controls, somehow make the C++ functions I want avaliable to UI. I need that library to be open source, and have same API for all platforms.

Comment: Have you looked at Qt's QML? I'm not sure whether it needs precompiling or not, though

Answer (score 1):

You could try wxWidgets, but to be honest, if Qt doesn't do it for you, I don't know why wxWidgets would be any better. You can do layout for the GUI with text files, and they aren't precompiled into C++ code (though I don't know why that's a plus).